# Strange behavior of 'ps -o pgid'

Tags: linux, process, ps, daemon

Intro: I have a daemon, which spawn processes and I have to stop it all gracefully. The solution I found on web based on pgid:

```
group_id=$(ps -o pgid= $(cat $pidfile))
if [ ! -z $group_id ]; then
        kill -- -$group_id
    success
fi
```

I was wondered how it works. And the first thing which I got stuck with is getting group_id. I can't get what's going here:

```
$ ps -o pgid= 21814
21813

$ ps -o pgid=21814
21814
3525
5180
```

But it seems, like I really need that first example with space after "=":

```
$ pstree -p | grep 21814
     |-python(21814)-+-python(21815)-+-{python}(21813)
```

Can anyone explain what's going on here? What I get as output of that examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equal symbol following a format flag (`-o format`) suppress the printing of the header that names the columns of option produced as the output.  This enables testing for null (empty) results.

By default, `ps` selects all processes with the same effective user ID as the current user of the terminal session.  Specifying the PID of interest after the `=` symbol infers that the header line contains that PID.  The other processes reported are those for you terminal session --- `bash` and the `ps` process itself.  You can see this if you do:

```
ps -o comm,pgid=21814
```